# mysqli_stmt_get_result - Fatal error

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un error en esta linea de codigo que no soy capaz de resolver. He mirado en muchos foros y muchos dicen que puede ser por la version de php. He estado comprobando en el phpmyadmin del servidor donde lo tengo alojado y permite usar esta funcion sin ningun problema. Adjunto codigo:

```
//subir a la base de datos
            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conexion);

            //obtener id usuario 
            session_start();

            $email = $_SESSION['usuario_email'];
            $nombreUsuario = $_SESSION['usuario_nombre'];
            $apellidoUsuario = $_SESSION['usuario_apellido'];
            $telefono = $_SESSION['usuario_telefono'];

            $sql_id = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre='$nombreUsuario' and apellido='$apellidoUsuario' and telefono=$telefono";

            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql_id)) {
                echo "SQL statement failed! Fallooo";
            }else{
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    $idUsuario = $row['id_usuario'];
                }
            }
```

La linea que da fallo es esta: `$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);`

Donde me addvierte de lo siguiente:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_stmt_get_result()

Espero que me podais ayudar, un saludo.

Comment: ¿que has comprobado concretamente en el phpMyAdmin?  ¿revisaste que tengas activados los drivers correspondientes? **"Both mysqlnd and nd_mysqli need to be enabled on your server if you wish to use this functionality."**   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001819/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysqli-stmt-get-result

Comment: he comprobado la documentacion que puedo usar, y entre las funciones que puedo usar viene la que me da el error. Ese link ya le habia visto, no ayudas copiando links de otra gente.

Comment: Pues si telefono es un campo integer y como bien has dicho te permite la función, yo he copiado y pegado tu codigo y funciona. Si no es por la BBDD, es que te falta algún driver

Comment: Oscar, por mucha documentación de phpMyAdmin que leas no te va a decir si tienes el servidor configurado como quieres. Si me dices que lo ves con `phpinfo()` me callo la boca, pero la documentación de una aplicación de terceros, no creo que asegure que a ti te tiene que funcionar (al menos en la documentación, si fuera un test que realiza ya no lo discutiría). Te pegué el enlace por si dicen algo que **se te ha pasado por alto**, eres libre de revisarlo o no, pero no creo que tu respuesta sea adecuada para con alguien que se ha molestado en leer tu problema y dedicarle algo de atención.

Comment: @Fly perdon si mi expresion te ha molestado, entonces, ¿que puedo hacer? porquela web esta en un servidor que no es mio, es del instituto

Comment: @Guillem el problema es que el servidor donde esta alojada la web no es mio, sino del instituto